# Transformar dimensões definidas em porcentagem para pixels usando jquery

Tags: jquery, css

De inicio já quero pedir desculpas pela típica pergunta de iniciante. Mas estou a um dia todo tentando achar em pixels as dimensões de determinado elemento da minha página mas não consigo.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $altura = $('#webcam').height();
  $largura = $('#webcam').width();

  alert('altura:' + $altura + ', largura:' + $largura);
  
});
```

```css
#webcam {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: black;
}

/* line 6, ../sass/_viewport.scss */
#webcam canvas, video {
    float: left;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
}
/* line 10, ../sass/_viewport.scss */
#webcam canvas.drawingBuffer, video.drawingBuffer{
    margin-left: calc(100% * (-1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="webcam">
  <video id="webcam-video" autoplay="true" preload="auto"></video>
  <canvas class="drawingBuffer" />
</div>
```

No alert a altura aparece de forma correta, mas a largura sempre aparece o valor em %. Qual seria a forma correta de fazer isso através de JQuery?

Comment: _"sempre aparece o valor em %"_... como assim? a mim não aparece `%`. Que browser estás a usar?

Comment: Podes usar este jsFiddle e adaptar para mostrar o problema? https://jsfiddle.net/urvwh9gy/

Comment: No localhost aparece sempre "largura:100" e caso eu mude o css para "width: 50%" o alert passa a exibir "largura:50".

Estou usando o Chrome e no jsFiddle funcionou corretamente (utilizando o mesmo navegador que uso para acessar o localhost).

Comment: E se inspecionares o elemento com as developer tools que largura dá?

Comment: div#webcam | 870 x 330

Comment: Estranho. E dificil de saber o que se passa se no jsFiddle funciona bem mas não no teu computador... O que dá: `alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('webcam')).width;`?

Comment: "100%"

Será que pode ser a versão do jquery? Atualmente uso a versão 2.2.0

Comment: Não é possivel saber o problema sem ter um exemplo do problema. O código que tens na pergunta é exatamente igual ao teu? Se não podes criar um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema? Sem isso lamento mas não podemos ajudar.

Comment: O código é exatamente esse da pergunta. Estranhamente no jsFiddle ele funciona e localmente não. Vou procurar por algum meio de resolver o problema e se achar comentarei aqui. De qualquer forma obrigado por ajudar.